# What are all these edits by 'Community'?

Tags: support, community-user

I keep seeing old questions popping up, marked as changed by the 'Community' user.

Today it was these:

- [Help for choosing a cost effective game server for Flash client](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23877/help-for-choosing-a-cost-effective-game-server-for-flash-client)
- [Events and objects being skipped in GameMaker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/events-and-objects-being-skipped-in-gamemaker)
- [2D character controller in unity (trying to get old-school platformers back)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/2d-character-controller-in-unity-trying-to-get-old-school-platformers-back)

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [user's profile](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) it reads:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users

So I think we're seeing those random pokes. Now, as for why it picks the questions it does, I don't know.

Comment: I believe it simply randomly picks questions with no upvoted answers -- the three questions under discussion certainly fit that criteria at the moment.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Yep, that's basically what it does.